# Perl Mechanize Returns Jumbled Text

Tags: perl, mechanize, www-mechanize

I have a form I would like to submit through the Mechanize module.

I have selected the `form_number` and did a `dump_forms()` and it returned

```
POST http://URL (multipart/form-data)
  field1=                (text)
  field2=                (text)
  field3=                (email)
  actionbutton=Enter     (submit)
```

Here is my resulting code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use WWW::Mechanize;
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();

my $url = "http://URL";
$mech->get($url);
$mech->form_number('1');
$mech->dump_forms();
my $result = $mech->submit_form(
    form_number => 1,
    fields       =>
    {
        field1 => 'Test1',
        field2 => 'Test2',
        email => 'test@email.com',
        actionbutton => 'Enter'
    },

);
print $result->content();
```

But here is what that outputs.

[image]

What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want `$result->decoded_content()`, not `$result->content()`.

See https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Response#r-content-bytes